# Общая база MySql Server для нескольких машин в сети

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlconnector

я новичок. Сейчас разрабатываю примитивную программу. Есть база данных (делал через MySQL Workbench), к которой я могу подключится. И в ней делать удаления, вставки, изменения в таблицу(в своей программе). 
Подключаюсь к БД так :

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=people;password=ASDasdasdasd1";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
```

Но когда скидываю на другой ПК. Она не работает(понимаю, ошибка в том что я указываю подключение к определенной БД и оно её не находит).
Вопрос. Как можно отображать данные на других ПК, где нету этого сервера и этой таблицы. Создавать свой файл *.sql? (Если да, то как его подключить)?

Answer (score 3):

Выделить один из компьютеров под сервер, с таким расчётом, чтобы IP-адрес (допустим, 192.168.1.100) этого сервера был доступен всем остальным машинам в сети.

Настроить на этом сервере MySql.

В конфиг-файлах клиентов указывать

```
string connStr = "server=192.168.1.100;user=root;database=people;password=ASDasdasdasd1";
```

На безрыбье (если нет компа или виртуалки под отдельный сервер) можете использовать IP-адрес своего компьютера и прописывать его в конфигах.

Но адрес localhost для подобной конфигурации использовать нельзя: это адрес, который не виден в сети, он на каждой машине ведёт на саму себя. Предполагается, что адрес у вас не меняется (а то dhcp на домашнем роутере может периодически менять адрес вашего компа)

Comment: Пару дополнений к ответу. MySQL по-умолчанию не разрешает удаленный доступ для пользователя root, потому вам придется создать спец.юзера для удаленного доступа, как это сделать можно найти... Если у вас динамическая адресация в сети, то вашему компу нужно назначить статический ip-адрес с помощью настроек в ОС или зайти в настройки роутера и прописать привязку mac-адреса сетевой карты вашего компа и назначаемого роутером ему ip-адреса.